# Best way to implement a true/false/undefined trichotomy variable in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, boolean

I'm temped to use an `int`, and make `0 == NO`, `1 == YES`, and anything else == undefined.
Obviously there are a million ways to do something like this, but what seems like the best way to you? Concerns I can think of include simplicity and memory footprint (e.g. what if I have a lot of these?).

Another way is to use two BOOLs, one for `isDefined`, and one for `value`

Another way,

`typedef enum { CPStatusUndefined, CPStatusAvailable, CPStatusUnavailable } CPStatus;`

Edit, the use case is:

I have a yes/no property that is difficult to calculate. When it is being checked, it is checked frequently (by `UIMenuController`, OFTEN), but unless the user selects it, it is never checked. The way I chose to deal with this is a tri-type variable. The first time you check, if it is undefined you calculate the yes/no value and return it, after that you just return the yes/no value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an enum.  In Objective-C they work just like they do in C/C++

```
typedef enum {
  No = 0,
  Yes,
  Other
} tri_type;

tri_type myVar = No;

if( myVar == Yes || myVar == Other ) {
  // whatever
}
```

Comment: @Kenny Don't try to be too clever. Use an enum with a nice, meaningful name.

Comment: @Kenny, +1 for meaningful names.

Answer (score 1):

How about `NSNumber`, since it can be `nil`?

```
[number boolValue] == YES;
[number boolValue] == NO;
[number boolValue] == nil; // or just number == nil
```

Comment: if `number` is `nil`, then `[number boolValue]` will be `NO`.  better to just check the variable itself.

Comment: Do the boolean representations actually need to be true/false, or is the use case more just that there need to be three potential values (i.e. like an `enum`)?  What exactly is the use case?

Comment: @Dave Sorry, totally missed that you weren't the OP :)

Comment: use case is I have a yes/no property that is difficult to calculate. When it is being checked, it is checked frequently (by UIMenuController, as much as 20 checks/sec), but unless the user selects it, it is never checked. Best way to handle this seems to be a tri-type. The first time you check, if it is undefined you calculate the yes/no value and return it, after that you just return the yes/no value.

Comment: Absolutely should be an enum then, I agree with Lee, and your own instinct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to conserve the most amount of memory, use a char.

char == 0, false
char == 1, true
else, undefined.

Obviously, you'll want to initialize it at something like -1.

This is the way obj-c does comparator return values:
if 0, they are equal.
if positive, a > b
if negative, a < b

Same idea as above.